# How do I compile a Codeblocks project made from CMake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, codeblocks

I am using CMake as my build system and I told it to generate Codeblocks MakeFiles. It did that successfully. Now I have a Codeblocks project that I've opened up and I don't know where to start creating an actual program to compile. What do I need to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have opened the project in CodeBlocks, it's CTRL-F9 to build (or menu "Build"->"Build"). This is for release 12.11, could have changed in more recent version.

Comment: I've done that and it does what it needs to do (what that is I'm not too sure) but I don't know where to put `main.cpp` and tell it to compile that source file. It has other cmake files and library files (from the library I'm using) and it builds those but I don't know how to tell cmake to build my cpp file.

Comment: The "build" operation is supposed to go through compiling+linking the files of the project, to produce an executable file (aka a "binary"), that you should find in the root folder of the project. But from your comment, it seems that the `main.cpp` is not in the project ? I am not an expert with CMake and how it produces the project file, but you can easily add the file manually: in "management" window, select the project, and righ-click->add files.

Comment: Even when I do add files it doesn't seem to do anything different. It just builds and then says it succeeded. No pop up window or anything.

Comment: Building a software is not supposed to produce some "popups" or anything flashy of that kind: it is supposed do "build" the software, that is produce some executable file in the root folder (or maybe under some `bin` folder, depends on some settings). It just tells you "ok" or "some errors occured". Have you checked with your file manager if the file is present or not ?

Comment: I looked everywhere in the build directory and I can't find any executable file relating to the project (I found two named a.exe but when I ran them they did nothing even when I have `cout << 123`). It tells me that no errors occurred. And in the Mangement section on the left hand side my `main.cpp` is within `Sources/sfml-build/main.cpp` and I made it apart of the project. I think the thing is that I haven't told make or cmake to compile the program...

Comment: Seems that there is a lot of confusion going around... CMake and make are two tools that serve different purposes. I suggest you start from more basic things: let the sfml library on the side for the moment, and try to build a simple "hello world" using Codeblocks. Figure out how the folders are organized, object files, executable files, project options, how Codeblocks manages all that, that sort of things. Once you are familiarized with all of this, then get back to your project.

Comment: Yes, I've been using Codeblocks for a long time and I know how most things are organized. The confusion here is that CMake generated a Codeblocks project for SFML, and I don't know how to add a file and tell CMake to compile that file.

Comment: Ok, so this is more a Cmake issue, then! But even is CMake doesn't add it to the project, it should be easy to add it manually from within Codeblocks, as stated in my first comment.

Comment: Yes but I've tried going to "Add file.." and I added a file called `main.cpp` to the project. It now appears as `Sources/main.cpp` in the project. Then I wrote in some code and I told it to build and run. It built and ran successfully (no errors or anything) but it never compiled `main.cpp` at all.